# Why is the Tableau Server check box grayed out for Enable Guest User?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to enable the Tableau Server guest account. I'm a server administrator. When I look at Server Settings > General > Guest Access > Enable Guest Access, the check box is grayed out and I'm not able to check it. Why is the Tableau Server check box grayed out for Enable Guest User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you a named user license or a core license? Guest access is only available for core licenses.

The other gotcha is that prior to Tableau 10.2, Guest user access was set for the entire server, not at the site level. Starting with 10.2, each site can independently set whether to allow guest users.

Comment: We have a named user license. I guess that's it. Thanks.